# SO_KEEPALIVE in Python on FreeBSD does not work

Tags: python, networking, tcp, websocket

I use this library:

https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server

When I run the below program (with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 on FreeBSD), it timeouts after 305 secs, despite I set `SO_KEEPALIVE`, that is `SO_KEEPALIVE` does not work!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

class MyWebSocket(WebSocket):
    def handleConnected(self):
        print(self.address, 'connected')
        self.client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
        #self.client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 3600)
        #self.client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 3600)
        self.client.settimeout(3600)


class MyWebSocketServer(SimpleWebSocketServer):
    def _decorateSocket(self, sock):
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
        #sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 3600)
        #sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 3600)
        sock.settimeout(3600)
        print("socket decorated: ", sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE))
        return sock


server = MyWebSocketServer('', 9000, MyWebSocket)
server.serveforever()
```

I use the following HTML for testing:

```
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><title>WebSocket</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket;
function setupWebSocket() {
  var host = "ws://XXX:9000/";
  try {
    socket = new WebSocket(host);
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    socket.onclose = function(msg) {
      var secs = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
      alert("disconnected after "+(secs/1000)+" sec");
    };
  }
  catch(ex){
    alert(ex);
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="setupWebSocket()">
</body>
</html>
```

Weirdly, similar code does work with PHP.

Comment: keepalive may not be configured on your server. I don't know how to check on freebsd. That doesn't explain why PHP works of course... just thinking of what I'd check.

Comment: keepalive is odd in that it may not be set during certain transitional states such as when a connect or accept is being negotiated. This can be a problem for async protocols that run on events. You could delay the set until some data arrives to check... but your test code would also have to send something.

Comment: TCP keep alive is not intended to keep the connection open but only to early detect broken connections where no clean shutdown was done.

Comment: What is the right way to keep connection (for which no essential data is passed during extended time) open?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is right - the socket stays open as long as the peer application keeps it open.... mostly. Intervening networks such as NATs, Firewalls and modem connections (I know, that is so 80's) may need to see traffic periodically to keep their part of the connection going. But the app itself doesn't see keepalive so if it has a connection timeout, it will still happen. Sometimes you can hack the app by sending something very uninteresting and some protcols allow for app level pings to keep alive.

Comment: Alternately... don't keep it alive. By the time a socket actually times out, the relative cost of a reconnect is rather small.

Comment: @tdelaney Adding to my test code "send something" and setting `SO_KEEPALIVE` after the data received does not help

Answer (score 2):

TCP keep alive is intended to detect if the peer is no longer reachable and to make sure that intermediate stateful packet filters (like employed in SoHo routers for NAT) don't throw the state away. It works by sending "empty" TCP packets with a payload size of 0.

Since TCP keep alive does not transport any data it will not help if you have an idle timeout at the application level which is triggered when no data are transferred. For this you need to send actual data, i.e. some kind of heartbeat. Websockets have "ping" and "pong" for this purpose, see the [documentation in python](http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.ping).

Comment: It seems that idle timeout happens on FreeBSD kernel level, not "the application level". So this does not help much

Comment: @porton: TCP sockets don't time out by default. But you might have somewhere configured a timeout on the socket (SO_TIMEOUT) or the WebSocket library does it. But this is an idle timeout (i.e. no data) so TCP keep alive does not help here either.

Comment: `grep -ri timeout ~/.local/lib/python3.5/` produces an empty output

Comment: I've read the source of the library. It has timeout only in `select()` call

Comment: @porton: since you use `settimeout(3600)` which sets the socket timeout it should not be the socket timeout, at least not on your site. But it can of course that the peer closes the idle connection. What *exactly* is the error you get (not shown in the question)?

Comment: What do you mean saying "it should not be the socket timeout"? "disconnected after 302.56 sec" is the alert produced by my JavaScript in the HTML

Comment: @porton: this is a disconnect and not a socket timeout. This means that the other site closed the idle connection. In this case setting a socket timeout on your site does not help since it only sets the timeout on your socket but not on the peers socket. So you need to set it on the other site too or you need to keep the connection busy with heartbeats.

Comment: This is a disconnect of my FreeBSD program from the browser (not another site). All I want is to prevent this disconnect, but I don't know how.

Comment: @porton: if it is the browser then there is probably no way to set socket timeouts there. Instead you have to keep the connection open with a heartbeat message (i.e. actual data) as I've told in my answer.

Comment: Because I managed to make the PHP code to work without such disconnects (using `SO_KEEPALIVE`), it seems that the side which breaks the connection is my Python code not the browser

Comment: @porton: I recommend that you do a packet capture and check which side closes the connection. The information you gave so far suggest that this is the browser.